# Any way to get null(empty) columns using IN condition in oracle? without using is null?

Tags: oracle, null

I have a *table*(employee) like below:

```
  EMPNO    ENAME      JOB          MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
  -------- ---------- --------- ------ ---------- -------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH                  7902 17/12/1980      800                    20
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN    7698 20/02/1981     1600        300         30
      7521 WARD                   7698 22/02/1981     1250        500         30
      7566 JONES      MANAGER     7839 02/04/1981     2975                    20
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN    7698 28/09/1981     1250       1400         30
      7698 BLAKE                  7839 01/05/1981     2850                    30
      7782 CLARK      TESTER      7839 09/06/1981     2450                    10
```

**Here what i need to get is:**
 employee **number**, **name** and job where **job** IN ('SALESMAN', 'MANAGER' and NULL(empty)).
I prepared a query by using `is NULL`

```
select empno, ename, job 
from employee 
where job in('SALESMAN', 'MANAGER') or job is null;
```

Is there any way, other than above Query?
can i pass null in side IN condition?

Comment: But why ? what's wrong with your query ?

Comment: ya, i need to pass job types as arguments in IN Condition.(is null is not required for my scenario). Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use nvl function:

```
select empno, ename, job 
from employee 
where nvl(job, 'NULL') in('SALESMAN', 'MANAGER', 'NULL')
```

Comment: Please note that this will prevent the use of an index on `job`, if such an index exists.